# Capitalisation of proverbs in titles

Tags: capitalization

In titles, do you capitalize all words in a proverb like "Better late than never" or only the first word?

Comment: There is no single answer. See the online tool [Title Case Converter](https://titlecaseconverter.com/), which lets you choose from among the common style guides.

Answer (score 1):

Rules for capitalisation (US: capitalization) of titles vary. The rules for a particular case will generally be found in a style guide, and most academic institutions and publishers either have their own, or require you to use one which they will indicate.

Most style guides require the following:

> Capitalise the first and last word of any title.
>
> Capitalize nouns, pronouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs.
>
> Do not capitalize articles, prepositions, or coordinating
>   conjunctions.

Thus, most style guides would require your title to be thus: **Better** (adverb) **Late** (adjective/adverb) **than** (preposition)  **Never** (adverb, and also last word).

Discussion:

[Capitalisation in Titles](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html)